# Implement Async and synchronous methods?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I follow Unit Of Work with generic repository pattern in my WebApi project. Currently I'm not using the **Async methods provided by Linq and EF6.

But I've started implementing async. So now a repository would look this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    T Get(int id);
    T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    Task<T> GetAsync(int id, CancellationToken ct);
    Task<T> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, CancellationToken ct);
}
```

And the unit of work:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<C>
{
    int Commit();
    Task<int> CommitAsync(CancellationToken ct);
}
```

I then have the service layer with all the service layers, and on top of that the controllers

Is it best practice to have both async and sync methods or just keep the async methods now?

Comment: It really depends on the use-case.
If you want to force all consumers of you API to be asynchronous, then expose only async endpoints. Otherwise, expose both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the approach is to expose both async and sync methods.

Another idea is to create a repository for each entity you refer to like:

```
  public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<UserModel, int>
    {
        UserModel GetByEmail(string email);
        Task<UserModel> GetByEmail(string email);
     }


 public interface IRepository<TModel, TKey> where TModel : class
    {
    }
```

You can try something like this but is just working smooth in theory because the Wait is blocking the current thread.

```
public static async Task<Model> GetModelAsync()
{
    // async logic & return task

}

public static Model CallGetModelAsyncAndWaitForResult()
{
    var task = GetModelAsync();
    task.Wait(); // Blocks current thread 
    var result = task.Result;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If the approach is to expose both methods, then the code will double in size. Or is it allowed to wrap aaync methods in sync methods?

Comment: You can write the async methods if you want any other logic happen there, and in your synced methods just use wait()